# Code First Migration - SQL Update column with data from another row in same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework-core, sql-update, ef-code-first

**Situation:**

Given is the following table:

| Id | Price | ProductId | ValidFrom |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1,00 | 1 | 01-01-01 |
| 2 | 1,00 | 1 | 01-01-15 |
| 3 | 1,00 | 1 | 01-02-01 |
| 4 | 1,00 | 2 | 01-01-01 |
| 5 | 1,00 | 2 | 01-01-11 |
| 6 | 1,00 | 2 | 01-01-28 |
| 7 | 1,00 | 2 | 01-02-01 |
| 8 | 1,00 | 2 | 01-01-08 |

Now I want to add a new column "ValidUntil" to the table. Because Data already exist the new column should be prefilled for existing entries.

The table should look like this after the change:

| Id | Price | ProductId | ValidFrom | ValidUntil |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1,00 | 1 | 01-01-01 | 01-01-15 |
| 2 | 1,00 | 1 | 01-01-15 | 01-02-01 |
| 3 | 1,00 | 1 | 01-02-01 |  |
| 4 | 1,00 | 2 | 01-01-01 | 01-01-11 |
| 5 | 1,00 | 2 | 01-01-11 | 01-01-28 |
| 6 | 1,00 | 2 | 01-01-28 | 01-02-01 |
| 7 | 1,00 | 2 | 01-02-01 | 01-02-08 |
| 8 | 1,00 | 2 | 01-02-08 |  |

I use Entity Framework Core Code First Migration to update the data.

**Problem:**

I rename the column first, thereafter I use the following line to prefill the column:

```
migrationBuilder.Sql("UPDATE Prices p1 SET p1.ValidUntil = (SELECT TOP 1 ValidFrom FROM Prices p2 WHERE p2.ValidFrom > p1.ValidFrom ORDER BY DATEDIFF(day, p2.ValidFrom, p1.ValidFrom))");
```

Runing the update I get the following errors:

> Incorrect syntax near 'p1'.

> Incorrect syntax near ORDER-Keyword.

**Question:**

I have less experience with SQL Statements so I would appreciate any help to understand what's wrong with this statement.

Also if anyone has a statement which would fit better for this case he is welcome too.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Oh, sorry. Sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `lead()` to get the until date:

```
select p.*,
       lead(validfrom) over (partition by productid order by validfrom) as validuntil
from prices p;
```

In SQL Server, you can incorporate this into an `update`:

```
with toupdate as (
      select p.*,
             lead(validfrom) over (partition by productid order by validfrom) as new_validuntil
      from prices p
     )
update toupdate
    set validuntil = new_validuntil
    where new_validuntil is not null;
```

Comment: Great! Thank you for the very fast response and great help. Worked for me!